# R raster functions, splitting multiple rasters from one

Tags: r, function, split, raster

I have a simple function splitting a raster object into three different classes. However my function doesn't return these rasters.  I also read this tutorial http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/functions.pdf
and according to it this is *"a really bad way of doing this"*. However the 'right way' seems overly complicated. Is it really that there is no simple way of doing this (i.e., considering functions should make things easier for you not the vice versa).

I'm quite new to processing rasters with R so forgive me my stupid question..

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))

r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[] <- rnorm(100,100,5)

# Create split function // three classes
splitrast <- function(rast, quantile) {
  print("Splitting raster...")
  (q <- quantile(rast, probs=quantile))
  r1 <- rast; r2 <- rast; r3 <- rast # copy raster three times

  r1[rast > q[1]] <- NA                    #raster value less than .25 quantile
  r2[rast <= q[1] | rast >= q[2]] <- NA    #raster values is between quantiles
  r3[rast < q[2]] <- NA                    #raster values is over .75 quantile
  par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  plot(r1);plot(r2);plot(r3)
  rast <-   brick(r1,r2,r3)
  return(rast)
}

splitrast(r,c(0.2,0.8))
ls()
```

EDIT: reproducible example added

Comment: You should store r1, r2 and r3 in a RasterStack and return this RasterStack as output of your function.

Comment: Or at least a list with three `RasterLayer`s.

Comment: as others have suggested, don't deal with 3 layers, deal with a `brick()` or a `stack()` (those two are very similar, and you can almost think of them as being an array, to the extent you can think of a raster as a matrix). Also, and more importantly, what does your function return (basics of R functions: you're only going to get r1; you could `return(list(r1,r2,r3))`)? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for ideas, but still not working.. btw. anyone now how to copy a raster n times? (line 3 in the function).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to return them separately. Instead `return(list(r1,r2,r3))`. But see comments about style.

Comment: If you do this, the returning object seems it becomes a type 'list', so when you try to access each of the elements, it seems they retain this type and I could ot convert them back to type 'S4'. Thus, applying (for example): "dim(raster_in_list)" that should return the rows and cols of the raster, actually returns 1 or NULL, if you try to dig in further in the object.

Comment: @Irene I posted this answer 4.5 years ago, so I don't quite remember. But a list is just a container. Try indexing it. Like `l = list()` then `l[[1]]`. Or, `mat_list = list(matrix(rep(1,6), nrow=3), matrix(rep(1,6), nrow=2))` then `sapply(mat_list, dim)` or `dim(mat_list[[1]])` etc. You just need to drill down to the actual raster, instead of using `dim` on the list itself, which returns the `dim` of the list, not the `dim` of the rasters inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

The R raster `subset` function can help here. After you return the brick, you can subset each band as separate rasters.

```
# split the raster - returns a three band stack
rasters = splitrast(r,c(0.2,0.8))

# subset each band of the stack as a separate raster
r1 = subset(rasters, 1)
r2 = subset(rasters, 2)
r3 = subset(rasters, 3)

# proof - plot the separate rasters - same as those plotted in the function
plot(r1);plot(r2);plot(r3)
```